# Time complexity of Swift 'compactMap' Sequence's method

Tags: swift, sequence

Swift documentation states that `compactMap()` method for sequenced has a time complexity of `O(n + m)` where n is the length of the sequence and m is the length of the result.

However, when looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a676a371f53941be5c499cf78ff8cbb7391af38c/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L802) in the standard library I cannot understand why:

```swift
public func _compactMap<ElementOfResult>(
    _ transform: (Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?
  ) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult] {
    var result: [ElementOfResult] = []
    for element in self {
      if let newElement = try transform(element) {
        result.append(newElement)
      }
    }
    return result
  }
```

There is only one loop over the sequence elements, it should be `O(n)`.

Comment: I think this might have been mistakenly copied over from the documentation of `flatMap(_:)`. You're right, in that it should be `O(self.count)` in both time and space.

Comment: Anything in comments and structured documentation is currently not to be trusted; compilers don't check it. Expect this to be the defining change of the next wave of programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation doesn't actually state whether that's the **time** or **memory complexity** of the algorithm.

The **time complexity** is `O(n)` indeed, however, the **memory complexity** is `O(n+m)`, since the original `Sequence` of size `n` is kept in memory, while a new `Array` of size `m` is also created.

Comment: Since m <= n, shouldn't it be just `O(n)`? Why mixing memory and time complexity like this? It makes understanding the documentation hard. `filter` also allocates a new array for result but its complexity is advertised as `O(n)`.

Comment: This isn't quite right, because the `Sequence` is being streamed into the array, but its elements aren't stored separately. Also, complexity analysis usually omits the size of the input.

Comment: Yes I read that `filter` is a consuming func (is it what you mean by 'streamed'?) so an iterator is created and consumed, but for a `Collection` the behavior should be virtually the same as `compactMap` in term of complexity?